# Docker Pull taking unexpectedly long time via Ansible

Tags: docker, ansible, amazon-ecr

Here is my setup:

I have a Master, where my playbook is running, and the workers[count = 3] where my plays are running, and I have a certain `docker pull` command to be executed.

The command[via Ansible] takes 6 mins to execute, when the same command takes ~1 min when done manually in the shell. [**Both tested in the same instance type and config.**]

Another interesting observation is: If the same command is run via Ansible **in localhost** (the master), it takes 1 minute only.

**Why is this happening? Why is the pull taking unexpectedly long time to complete in the workers?**

PS: Pulling from an AWS ECR registry.

Answer (score 0):

There is an Ansible module for that, https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/docker_container_module.html I'm using it in some playbooks, works like a charm. Consider using it if you want better performance.

Edit (thanks That lazy iOS Guy) : for example in you case,

```
- name: Pull a container image
  docker_container:
    name: myrepo/myimage
    image: busybox
    pull: yes
    state: present
```

pull is the most important thing for you here.